# Conditional operations on a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With this two simplified dataframes

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],'YEAR':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3],'VALUE':[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY':['A','A','B','B','C'],'YEAR':[1,3,1,2,3],'PROPORTION':[0.5,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.1]})
```

df1

```
  COUNTRY  YEAR  VALUE
0       A     1    100
1       A     2    100
2       A     3    100
3       B     1    100
4       B     2    100
5       C     1    100
6       C     2    100
7       C     3    100
```

df2

```
  COUNTRY  YEAR  PROPORTION
0       A     1         0.5
1       A     3         0.1
2       B     1         0.5
3       B     2         0.2
4       C     3         0.1
```

How can I multiply `df1.VALUE` by `df2.PROPORTION` matching `df1.COUNTRY=df2.COUNTRY` and `df1.YEAR=df2.YEAR` resulting in

```
VALUE=[50,100,10,50,20,100,100,10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use pandas intrinsic data alignment with indexes.
Use `set_index` and `mul` with `fill_value=1`.

```
df1i = df1.set_index(['COUNTRY','YEAR'])
df2i = df2.set_index(['COUNTRY','YEAR'])

df2i['PROPORTION'].mul(df1i['VALUE'], fill_value=1).rename('PROPORTION').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  COUNTRY  YEAR  PROPORTION
0       A     1        50.0
1       A     2       100.0
2       A     3        10.0
3       B     1        50.0
4       B     2        20.0
5       C     1       100.0
6       C     2       100.0
7       C     3        10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `merge` then `mul`

```
df1['New Value']=df1.merge(df2,how='left').PROPORTION.mul(df1.VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],'YEAR':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3],'VALUE':[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY':['A','A','B','B','C'],'YEAR':[1,3,1,2,3],'PROPORTION':[0.5,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.1]})
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['COUNTRY', 'YEAR'], how='left').fillna(1)
df['res'] = df['VALUE']*df['PROPORTION']
df
```

The output:

```
    COUNTRY YEAR    VALUE   PROPORTION  res
0   A   1   100 0.5 50.0
1   A   2   100 1.0 100.0
2   A   3   100 0.1 10.0
3   B   1   100 0.5 50.0
4   B   2   100 0.2 20.0
5   C   1   100 1.0 100.0
6   C   2   100 1.0 100.0
7   C   3   100 0.1 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['VALUE']=df1.merge(df2,how='left').fillna(1)['PROPORTION'].mul(df1['VALUE'])
```